# Determinar posicion y repeticion en un array tipo "double" con numeros aleatorios

Tags: java, array, double

Ocupo solicitarle al usuario un número entre 1 y 50 por pantalla e
indícar si este número se encuentra dentro del vector generado, cuantas veces se
repite y en qué posiciones pero no logro encontrar una manera para determinar en cual posicion se repite ni cuantas veces. Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento, Gracias!

```
 public static void aleatorio(){
    
            
     double a[]=new double[100];
    double vecesQueSeRepite=0,pos_menor=0,pos=0;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Digite un numero");
    double num=sc.nextDouble();
    
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         a[i]=(int)(Math.random()*50+1);
       if(a[i]==num){
           System.out.println("El número se repite");
      
           
           
           }else{
           System.out.println("No se repite");
       
       
       
           
       } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber cuántas veces se repite y sus posiciones

```
int contRepeticiones = 0;
ArrayList<int> posiciones = new ArrayList<int>();


for(int i = 0; i<a.Length;i++)
{
    if(a[i] == núm)
    {
       posiciones.Add(i);
       contRepeticiones++;
    }
}
```

Lo que hace este código para saber cuántas veces se repite el número es que se declara afuera del ciclo un contador de repeticiones inicializado en 0. Luego se recorre el arreglo preguntando si hay algún elemento del arreglo que sea igual al número que buscas de encontrarse ese número pues se incrementa en uno el contador. Este contador es el que debes imprimir por pantalla mostrando la cantidad de veces que se repite en el arreglo

Para saber las posiciones creo una lista igualmente afuera del ciclo , cuando se entra al ciclo y coincida un elemento del arreglo con el número buscado pues añado la posición que en este caso es i a la lista de posiciones

Para imprimir las posiciones tengo que poner otro ciclo

```
for(int i = 0; i<posiciones.Length; i++)
{
    Imprimo las posiciones
}
```

y después borro la lista de posiciones

```
   posiciones.Clear();
```